# TinyMCE text editor reset

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE editor version 3.5 with jQuery. I'm having problem when I'm trying to change the content of the editor. I'm receiving some content from AJAX request and then I want to put it in the editable area. So I write:

```
#('#my-textarea-id').html(ajax_result);
// OR
#('#my-textarea-id').val(ajax_result);
```

It works fine the first two times I use it, but after that it doesn't change and stays on first selected value. It's very strange. What may cause the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `tinymce.get('#my-textarea-id').setContent(ajax_result);`

Comment: And console.log(tinymce.get('#my-textarea-id')) returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. Even tinyMCE creation is a few lines above changing it's content, it hasn't finished and that's why it returns undefined. Now everything is ok. Thank you. :)